# Using collection inside Iron Router's onBeforeAction

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I a collection called Tabs and a dynamic route with tabId as its route parameter. A tab has a boolean attribute 'published', and I want to redirect a user back to the root url, if they visit a route, to which the corresponding tab record's 'published' is false.

To do this I figured I could just fetch the record in the onBeforeAction and check it, but the cursors returned from the subscription is undefined for some reason.

Route:

```
viewTabController = RouteController.extend({
  layoutTemplate: 'storeLayout',
  subscriptions: function() {
    var tabId    = this.params.tabId;
    var sourceId = readCookie(Purchases.COOKIE_IDENTIFIER(tabId));

    this.sub     = Meteor.subscribe("itemData", tabId, sourceId);
  },
  data: function() {
    var tabId = this.params.tabId;
    return {
      tab:      Tabs.findOne(tabId),
      ready:    this.sub.ready
    };
  },
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    if (this.sub.ready) {
      var tab      = Tabs.findOne(); <------------ undefined
      var purchase = Purchases.findOne(); <-------------- undefined

      console.log(tab, purchase);

      if (!_.isUndefined(purchase)) {
        console.log('go receipt');
        // Router.go('receipt', { purchaseId: purchase._id });
      } else if (!tab.isPublished()) {
        console.log('is not Published');
      } else {
        console.log('view tab');
      }
    }
    this.next();
  },
  onAfterAction: function() {
    SEO.set({
      title: 'View Tab | ' + SEO.settings.title
    });
  },
  fastRender: true
});

Router.route('viewTab', {
  path: '/tabs/:tabId',
  controller: viewTabController
});
```

Publication using publishComposite:

```
/*
 * Returns tab matching ID
 */
Meteor.publishComposite("itemData", function(tabId, sourceId) {
  check(tabId, String);

  return {
    find: function() {
      return Tabs.find({ _id: tabId }, { fields: { downloadUrl: 0, s3key: 0, createdAt: 0 } });
    },
    children: [
      {
        find: function(tab) {
          return Users.find({ _id: tab.userId }, { fields: { username: 1 } });
        }
      },
      {
        find: function(tab) {
          return Purchases.find({ tabId: tabId, sourceId: sourceId });
        }
      }
    ]
  };
});
```

Is this the wrong approach or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer but I hope it helps further.

The problem is that Tabs & Purchases.FindOne() is not ready yet when it is supposed to be used, [please read this great post for clarification](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards).